# Did Rafael Lemkin predict antisemitic mass murders before WWII?

Tags: nazi-germany, holocaust, antisemitism

I recall from reading Phillipe Sands East West Street that [Raphael Lemkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphael_Lemkin#Career_in_interwar_Poland) (who would later term the word Genocide) drew paralells between the Armenian Genocide and the disenfranchisment of Jews in Germany starting in '33, going so far as predicting the  mass murder  to come (or at least seeing the real danger).

However I don't have access to the book right now. I'm not sure my memory is correct, and totally unsure when *exactly* Lemkin made this prediction, if at all. Both Wikipedia articles I can read on him don't state explicitly what he said or wrote *before the outbreak of the war* about antisemitism and it's possible consequences in Germany.

This question is in part prompted by reading David Cesaranis The Fate of the European Jews, as Cesarani quotes many German Jews who did not see their lives in danger in the pre-war years.

Comment: As [The Bard said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subterranean_Homesick_Blues), you don't need a weatherman to know which way the wind blows.

Comment: Pogroms had been common in Europe long before the Nazis.

Comment: The famous Russian (later Soviet) writer [Ilya Ehrenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilya_Ehrenburg) in his adventure satirical novel _The Extraordinary Adventures of Julio Jurenito and his Disciples_ (1922) predicted not only deportation and burning the Jews, but also Americans using atomic weapons in Japan. The novel tells the story of an adventurer Julio Jurenito, "The Teacher", and his disciples during WWI, in France, Belgium, Germany and finally Russia during the Civil War. The novel is highly recommended.

Comment: Neither the holocaust, nor the Armenian genocide where pogroms.